# iPhoto-readable 'tags' - editing possible on iPod Touch/iPhone?

Tags: ios

I'd like to create/edit the tags on my photos on my iPod Touch, such that they are sync'd back to iPhoto.  Presumably, iPhoto would then update my smart albums.

I find it's such a chore to do it on my Mac, so I never get the task done.  If it is possible to do it in smaller chunks on my iPod Touch, I'd prefer it.

Hoping against hope,
Eric